# Extract password from securestring in batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to extract password from securestring in batch.

This is in PS:

```
Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString |  ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\Temp\Password.txt"
$pass = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$stringValue = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass));
```

It works as expected.

I am converting the above code in batch:

```
powershell -Command "& {Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString |  ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\Temp\Password.txt"}" 
powershell -command "& {$pass = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString; ^
$stringValue = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass))}"
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %v IN (`stringValue`) DO set "d=%v"
echo %d%
```

I am not sure if what is wrong, I only get  "**powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand**" on **echo %d%**, not the plaintext password.

Comment: PowerShell variables don't magically become batch variables. You need to run the PowerShell code inside the backticks and echo the decrypted password there.

Comment: I have tried it. I get the same result.

Comment: Why use a batch file at all? Just use PowerShell and you can avoid most of the painful contortions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to echo out `$stringValue`, before you are able to use it in cmd. 
You could replace the assignment to `$stringValue` with an echo of the conversion result and embed this in your for "loop".

**EDIT:**

Let's write some code.

```
:: Write the password to File (unchanged)
powershell -Command "& {Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString |  ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\Temp\Password.txt"}"

::Read in the file, echo it out. (changed at the end)
powershell -command "& {$pass = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString; $stringValue = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass));echo $stringValue}"
```

The last line in the code above gives out the password in plain text.
Now you just embed this last line to your for loop instead of just echoing out the password:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %v IN (`powershell -command "& {$pass = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString; $stringValue = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass));echo $stringValue}"`) DO set "d=%v"
```

And now, echo will give me the password:

```
C:\Temp> FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %v IN (`powershell -command "& {$pass = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString; $stringValue = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass));echo $stringValue}"`) DO set "d=%v"
C:\Temp> set "d=asdf"
C:\Temp> echo %d%
asdf
C:\Temp>
```

Comment: I tried this: set pscmd=powershell -Command "&{$pass=Get-Content 'C:\Temp\Password.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString;$bstr=

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass);$str=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR

($bstr);[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)}"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%pscmd%`) do set password=%%p
echo %password% - I am still unable to decrypt the password. I am not sure how to echo out otherwise. I am quite new to this scripting. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: replace the second PowerShell command and the rest of the script with `powershell -command "& {$pass = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString; $stringValue = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pass));echo $stringValue}"`. This ould echo out the decrypted password.

Comment: @Prasu: I changed my answer and added the solution as a code block. Tried it locally and it worked like expected. Please give feedback on this.

Comment: Add parenthesis to the last section on the first line, otherwise, the code might run locally but might not when someone else runs it. This is what happened to one of my PowerShell scripts :
do (set Password=%%a)